# Laravel storage issue with windows apache virtual host

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-storage

I'm having issue with Laravel storage displaying image. i've enabled virtual host but when i click on the image url it goes to `http://localhost/storage/`. The same issue even with `php artisan serve`
Here is the code on my blade:

```
 @foreach($course->thumbnail as $key => $media)
                                    <a href="{{ $media->getUrl() }}" target="_blank" style="display: inline-block">
                                        <img src="{{ $media->getUrl('thumb') }}">
                                    </a>
                                @endforeach
```

Any help is appreciated,

Comment: This question can be closed as "not reproducible or typo".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have posted this too early lol, got it solved :) Apparently i forget to change the URL on the **.env** file to the virtual host.